# Converting nvarchar to date - getting conversion string to datetime error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched and tried everything to resolve this issue but no luck. I have a date (`Start_Date`) in `12/1/2017` format (datatype `nvarchar`) and I need to convert it to a date `2017-12-01` format in order to compare against another start date that is in `2017-12-01` format.

I tried

```
UPDATE #temp2 
SET [start_date] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,[start_date], 105))
```

but I get this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: The best fix for this is: **Don't store dates in varchar columns!**

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `DECLARE @s nvarchar(255)
SET @s = '12/1/2017'
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,@s,105))` works fine. But why are you converting back to nvarchar again? Convert both values to datetimes and then compare them.

Comment: smalldatetimes still have a time aspect to them, try converting to date

Comment: I'm hazard a guess that you have a value that isn't confirming to your formatting; this is why it's a bad idea sotring a `date(time)` as a `(n)varchar`. What is the result of `SELECT start+date FROM #temp2 WHERE TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime,start_date,105) IS NULL AND start_Date IS NOT NULL;`?

Comment: Let this be a lesson to never store date as varchar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cast()` don't need to use style code :

```
select *
from #temp2 t
where cast([start_date] as date) = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
update #temp2
    set [start_date] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), TRY_CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,[start_date], 105))
    where TRY_CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, [start_date]) is not null;
```

This would update the values where the string represents a date, while preserving the values of the rest.